# Fieldset equivalent in flex 4?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

can any one help me out to solve my doubt.I need to group some components into a group and assign a name to it which should look like "fieldset" in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed something like this and found a perfect solution [here](http://blog.devinholloway.com/2012/03/flex-fieldset-component.html).

An example looks so in HTML:

[image]

and so in Flex:

[image]

It was not easy to get a working version of it. You can find my source [here](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/fieldset/src.7z).

The working example is [here](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/webspark46/fieldset/).

Thanks to Devin Holloway!!!

Comment: thanks its working when we import it as a separate project.But when i include it in my project file it is giving an error <com:FieldSet> cannot be resolved.

Comment: You should check paths to the components. In best case you can create your own flex library with the component. Let me know if you have problems with it.